Shared library (dll) I wrote does not load from LuaLateX
I want to use a Lua module I am writing with Lua API C called luamathminimal.
I work on Windows 11.
I have compiled Lua 5.3.6 because LuaTeX runs it (Paragraph 4.2.1 The LUA version in LuaTex Manual) and its installation is located in my at PC "C:\src\lua" folder.
My Lua interpreter is compiled with cygwin using C compiler x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc via make file and -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN flag on.
LUA_CPATH is setted as C:/src/lua/share/lua/5.3/?/?.dll
My LUA API C library source code is formed by following files and folder tree:
..\luamathminimal\include\luamath_minimal.h
..\luamathminimal\include\luamath_minimal_fun.h
..\luamathminimal\src\luamath_minimal.c
..\luamathminimal\src\luamath_minimal_fun.c

The source code it is zipped and downloadable HERE.
EDIT: The source code can be seen and downloaded from github HERE
I compile luamathminimal linking it with lua53.dll following the steps below (.. means general path):
x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc -O2 -c -DLUA_CORE -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL -o ../luamathminimal/src/luamath_minimal.o ../luamathminimal/src/luamath_minimal.c -I"C:/src/lua/include" -I"../luamathminimal/include"

x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc -O2 -c -DLUA_CORE -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL -o ../luamathminimal/src/luamath_minimal_fun.o ../luamathminimal/src/luamath_minimal_fun.c -I"C:/src/lua/include" -I"../luamathminimal/include"

x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc -O2 -Wall -shared -fPIC -o C:/src/lua/luamathminimal/lib/luamathminimal.dll ../luamathminimal/src/luamath_minimal.o ../luamathminimal/src/luamath_minimal_fun.o -L"C:/src/lua/bin" -llua53

When I call luamathminimal from lua using lua interpreter, I have no problem at all (see luamath_minimal_test_01.lua file).
When I call luamathminimal from LuaLaTeX using luapackageloader package with the following comand:
lualatex --shell-escape luamath_minimal_test.tex

the LuaLaTeX compiler stops releasing the following feedback (see also luamath_minimal_test.tex file):
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 system commands enabled.
(./luamath_minimal_test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luapackageloader/luapackageloader.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./luamath_minimal_test.aux)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

EDIT N°2: running gdb, the feedback is the following:
Starting program: /cygdrive/c/texlive/2024/bin/windows/lualatex --shell-escape luamath_test.tex
[New Thread 988.0x1ea4]
[New Thread 988.0x1ef0]
[New Thread 988.0x4ddc]
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)
 system commands enabled.
(./luamath_test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luapackageloader/luapackageloader.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./luamath_test.aux) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)warning:

 *** A stack buffer overrun occurred in C:\texlive\2024\bin\windows\lualatex.exe --shell-escape luamath_test.tex:

warning: This is usually the result of a memory copy to a local buffer or structure where the size is not properly calculated/checked.
warning: If this bug ends up in the shipping product, it could be a severe security hole.
warning: The stack trace should show the guilty function (the function directly above __report_gsfailure).
warning:  *** enter .exr 00007FFB13A13F80 for the exception record
warning:  *** then kb to get the faulting stack


Thread 1 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ffb1399e275 in ntdll!RtlUnhandledExceptionFilter2 () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffb1399e275 <ntdll!RtlUnhandledExceptionFilter2+869>:     mov    (%r14),%r9
2: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffb1399e275 <ntdll!RtlUnhandledExceptionFilter2+869>:     mov    (%r14),%r9
(gdb)

How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

questions should be self-contained and lots of people won't download random zips from strangers on the net. if the code works fine independently, I suggest adding at least a minimal .tex here which produces the issue and the log file. you can also try enabling more verbose output, especially if compilation just hangs or dies. I'm not sure whether you are saying it hangs i.e. the process continues to run but never produces any further output or whether it dies without producing more output or something else. you could also try substituting texlua for your compiled lua to test.

but note that the version of lua luatex uses is not quite the same as the standalone interpreter, as I understand it, even if the versions are nominally the same.

You can include the headers from any version of Lua 5.3 (-I header/path), but you can only link to the Lua library provided by LuaTeX (-L path/to/luatex -llua53w64). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726256/270600 for some more details.

@cfr: the code stops as I show in the question

@MaxChernoff: I already did it but the result is the same. :-(

@Azoun Hmm, segfault maybe? Can you try running lualatex under gdb?

@cfr : I added github link to permit all to see the code without download zip file :-)

@MaxChernoff : it seems not working: Reading symbols from lualatex... (No debugging symbols found in lualatex)

@Azoun That's to be expected, and hopefully shouldn't be an issue. More specific instructions: run gdb --args lualatex --shell-escape luamath_minimal_test.tex, then at the (gdb) prompt type r<enter>. If everything runs properly, it should (eventually) output [Inferior 1 (process XXX) exited normally]; if there's an error in your C module, you'll probably see Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault followed by the line that caused the error.

@MaxChernoff : you can read the error in the edited question.

@Azoun Ok, so that means that there's probably a bug in your C code somewhere (although it could be in the engine too). Try compiling your code with debugging symbols (gcc -O0 -ggdb3 […], run with gdb, then after you get that warning, type in bt<enter>. Hopefully that should point you to the offending line; if not, you'll need to compile LuaTeX with debugging symbols (git clone --depth 1 https://gitlab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/texlive/luatex.git, ./build.sh --parallel --luahb --debug, install the binaries, and then run fmtutil-sys --all) and try gdb again.
